# JTextArea. How can I replace text when printing new one?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, keylistener

I created JFrame and JTextArea above it. JTextArea has defaul text "*This is text for demo version*", that has been set via setText() method.

[image]

**The goal is** to implement this logic:
If I start printing text, the old text should be deleted and new one should apper.
After that, when new text is printed and if I click "Enter" - new text should be saved into  `private ArrayList<String> textList`

[image]

The main question is How to replace old text when I print the first symbol of my text?

I tried to add `TestTextArea.this.replaceRange(keyText,0, 30);` inside keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}; (30 it's the last index of default string "*This is text for demo version*" ). But everytime when I print anything, it causes **IllegalArgumentException** and seems that old text is still visible on the background.

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

public class TestTextArea extends JTextArea {

    private String text = "This is text for demo version";
    private ArrayList<String> textList = new ArrayList<>();

    TestTextArea() {
        setBackground(new Color(23, 28, 34, 240));
        setForeground(new Color(6, 200, 109));
        setCaretColor(new Color(6, 200, 109));
        setCaretPosition(0);
        setFont(new Font("Helvetica Neue", Font.BOLD, 16));
        setText(text);
        setLineWrap(true);
        setWrapStyleWord(true);
        setFocusable(true);
        setEnabled(true);
        setEditable(true);
        setVisible(true);

        addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                String keyText = KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode());
                TestTextArea.this.replaceRange(keyText,0, 30);
                if (keyText.equals("Enter")) {
                    textList.add(TestTextArea.this.getText());
                }
            }
        });

    }
    public static void main(String []args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        TestTextArea area = new TestTextArea();
        f.add(area);

        f.setSize(400,200);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Is there any another way to solve this? I want that after I type the text and press Enter, all the text that I typed is saved. But at the moment it turns out that when you enter the first character, the default text is deleted, but even no one character is saved.

I am sorry, in advance for the possibly not very successful statement of the problem.

Comment: @Abra I need an input field, but it shouldn't look like a JTextField. Many sentences can be entered in the input field and words must wrap to the next line. Further, when a line or at least one character is entered, the user can press Enter and the data that he entered must be saved to the list. This is why I chose the JTextArea, as it can be stretched to fit the entire JFrame. Thanks for your advice on Text Prompt, but I don't want to resort to using third-party libraries just yet.

Comment: If I understand the requirement You want an Action so that when Enter is pressed you 1) save the current text to the ArrayList 2) set a flag so that the next character to be added to the Document will cause the previous text to be deleted from the document first.

Comment: @camickr In fact, everything is more complicated. This is just a demo example. In my real application, this JFrame is an add-on that appears after clicking a specific button. The following is the logic. 1) If we press Esc, the additional frame should be disposed. 2) If we press Enter and the entered value is not equal to an empty string, then it is written to the list and the additional frame should be disposed.

But in this specific example for the demo, I want to achieve exactly the logic that I described above, everything else with disposing the frame is done very easily.

Comment: The other logic is irrelevant to your stated question. I was asking for clarity of this specific requirement. Your originally stated: **I want that after I type the text and press Enter, all the text that I typed is saved.** So, you suggested the text should only be saved. Now you are saying the text should be "saved" and "deleted" so the text area contains no text?

Comment: If this is supposed to be an additional application JFrame, perhaps a JDialog would be a better choice.

Comment: @camickr No, a little different. Initially, there is **default text** in the JTextArea ("This is text for demo version"). As soon as at least one button is pressed, the **default text** should disappear and only the character that was entered should be displayed. Characters can be entered until Enter is pressed. As soon as Enter is pressed, all characters that have been entered are saved to the list. There should be no logic to delete characters after pressing Enter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand your requirements.

- When the first character is typed, clear the `JTextArea` and capture the typed text in the `JTextArea`,
- When the Enter key is pressed, save the typed text in the `List`.

This code meets these requirements.

I use a `JTextArea`.  The only reason you extend a Swing component, or any Java class, is to override one or more of the class methods.

I set the size of the `JTextArea` in the `JTextArea` constructor.  Then I `pack` the `JFrame`.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TextEntryExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TextEntryExample());
    }
    
    private List<String> textList;
    
    private String text;
    
    private JTextArea textArea;
    
    public TextEntryExample() {
        this.text = "This is text for demo version";
        this.textList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.textArea = createPrompt();
        f.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JTextArea createPrompt() {
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 30);
        textArea.addKeyListener(new PromptListener());
        textArea.setBackground(new Color(23, 28, 34, 240));
        textArea.setForeground(new Color(6, 200, 109));
        textArea.setCaretColor(new Color(6, 200, 109));
        textArea.setCaretPosition(0);
        textArea.setFont(new Font("Helvetica Neue", Font.BOLD, 16));
        textArea.setText(text);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        
        return textArea;
    }
    
    public class PromptListener implements KeyListener {
        
        private boolean entry;
        
        public PromptListener() {
            this.entry = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
            if (!entry) {
                String oldText = textArea.getText();
                textArea.replaceRange("", 0, oldText.length());
                entry = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
            if (entry) {
                String keyText = KeyEvent.getKeyText(event.getKeyCode());
                if (keyText.equals("Enter")) {
                    textList.add(textArea.getText());
                    entry = false;
                }
            } 
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, you understood everything correctly, thank you so much, the problem is solved!

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the easiest, but you could replace the document with one that clears the text on the first edit.

I haven't checked, but I think JTextArea uses a DefaultStyledDocument. You can extend that and override the editing methods to check a flag - if it's set, clear the text and clear the flag. I've done something similar this for JTextField (using PlainDocument) - here's how that would look:

```
public class PromptDocument
    extends PlainDocument
{
    private bool clearOnEdit = false;

    public void insertString(int offset, String str, AttributeSet a)
        throws BadLocationException
    {
        if (clearOnEdit) {
            super.remove(offset, getLength());
            clearOnEdit = false;
        }
        super.insertString(offset, str, a);
    }
    public void remove(int offset, int len)
        throws BadLocationException
    {
        if (clearOnEdit) {
            super.remove(offset, getLength());
            clearOnEdit = false;
        } else {
            super.remove(offset, len);
        }
    }
    public void setClearOnEdit(final boolean clear) {
        clearOnEdit = clear;
    }
}
```

It should be similar for JTextArea (I haven't tested this, might be missing things). You can just use `setDocument()` on your JTextArea after you create it.

Comment: Looks good, there is only one problem, my default text disappered before entering smth :)

Comment: Could you please edit your code and write remove method too? I found only removeUpdate() method in parent PlainDocument class.

Comment: @Neo Why? What do you expect to happen for the "revoveUpdate() method?

Comment: I saw the comment // ...similar thing for remove(), but I didn't know which method should I override. Anyway, I fixed the issue that default text was invisible. I just added ``` setDocument() ``` before adding setText() to JTextArea.
But I faced with new issue. If I click and put mouse cursor somewhere between chars of default text and start typing, default text not removed. It is just edited with the addition of new entered characters

Comment: Yeah, I guess this doesn't work the way you want, sorry. The insert/remove methods are only called when the edit is complete. You might be able to do something by listening to the focus instead?

Comment: I am trying to find work around. I will transform my default text to char Array. Will try to check if input field contains smth like my default text but with another symbols inside, I will remove all edited string. This is not a good approach, but will try to do this.